# Regex to validate kilograms (3 decimal places)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a pattern to validate kg.

for example:

Valid values

```
0.350
12.100
0.100
```

Invalid values

```
0.1a
1.b0
1a.0
```

Comment: Sorry, but why is the second set of values invalid? To me they seem perfectly fine as kilogram values.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with kilograms? It looks like you just want to enforce 3 decimal places?

Comment: Do you mean you always want 3 digits after the decimal point?

Comment: nfechner you're correct, I edit the question
Widor yes, i always want 3 decimal places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will match `{1 or above number of digits}{a dot}{exactly 3 digits}`

```
\d+\.\d{3}
```

Comment: @Alexandre, this will also match "1.1234" and "1.123Foobar" and "Foo12.123bar". But if you add the anchors `^` and `$` at the start and the end it should do what you want. Correct solution: `^\d+\.\d{3}$` (Or if you want to match those values in the middle of the text use `\b\d+\.\d{3}\b`)

Comment: @stema Had the same though. The question is rather vague. Probably \b should suffice too.

Comment: @stema Yes, I saw it but it was not there when I wrote that! Sorry :)